# React: como puedo redirigir a otra ruta luego de haberme logueado

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

entiendo la navegación con el componente {Navigate} que ofrece "react-router-dom" pero aqui es un evento "onSubmit" no entiendo muy bien como funciona el enrutamiento en un metodo.

App.js

```
function App() {

  const { rol } = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {/* inicia el login la peticion al rest-api */}
          <Route index path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
          {/* de acuerdo a su rol debe redireccionarlo a la ruta indicada */}
          <Route  path="/admin" element={<Admin actor="admin"/>}/>
          <Route  path="/facturador" element={<Facturador/>}/>
          <Route  path="/compras" element={<Compras/>}/>
          <Route  path="/ventas" element={<Ventas/>}/>
          <Route  path="/recepcion" element={<Recepcion/>}/>
          <Route  path="*" element={<h1>404</h1>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../context/UserContext.js";


function Login() {

  const { setUserName , setUserRol , use , rol } = useContext(UserContext);

  function handlerUser(e){
    setUserName(e.target.value)
    setUserRol("admin")
  }

  // peticion al rest-api 
  function handlerSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    // en esta parte 
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
        <div
          className="border p-3 shadow"
          style={{ width: "350px", height: "250px" }}
        >
          <h2 className="text-center">Login</h2>
          <form className="text-center mt-4" onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control text-center"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                placeholder="username"
                onChange={handlerUser}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control text-center"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
                placeholder="password"
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Ingresar
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

El rol definido es admin para poder redireccionarlo y tambien estoy usando un contexto que engloba el componente app.js. intente hacerlo con window.location y otro metodos de javaScript pero fallan es decir reinician el navegador lo cual coloca como null las variables de mi contexto.

He usado los hooks withRouter, useHistory. pero al parecer ya no estan disponibles en la nueva version de react-router React 18.2 me indica react un error de los metodos y objetos disponibles en ese modulo pero no estan ya disponibles.

Comment: Qué versión de react-router-dom estás utilizando? la última?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0","react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useHistory es un hook que se usaba en react-router-dom v5, así que como estás usando la versión 6, necesitar usar ahora [useNavigate](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/)

```js
let navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('admin', { replace: true }) // Aquí ponemos replace:true para reemplazar la ruta actual con la tuya, pues si usaramos el navigate por sí solo, pushearía la ruta por encima de la otra
```

Comment: No tenia conocimiento de ese modulo. funciona perfectamente.